# How do I slow down the banner transitions on my homepage? CSS

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

On my homepage the banner transitions are going very quickly- I would like to know how to slow them down. Here is the page: www.sevenbarfoundation.org

It is written in CSS

Comment: Maybe better suited to the webmasters, but should probably be made more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under:

> http://assets.sevenbarfoundation.org/wp-content/themes/sevenbar/js/slideshow.js

You need to change the values in line 14 and 15 to have the effect you want (timeout and speed):

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    timeout: 1000, 
    speed:   1000,
    pager:  '#slideshow_controls_num'
});
```